# How do you know how many arguments a function retrieved via getattr() take?

Tags: python-2.7

If you retrieved an attribute via `getattr()`, how do you check:

- that it is a function
- how many arguments this function takes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [50]: class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 4
    def somefunc(self, x, y):
        self.a = x+y
   ....:         

In [51]: type(getattr(Foo, 'somefunc'))
Out[51]: function

In [52]: getattr(Foo, 'somefunc').__code__.co_argcount
Out[52]: 3
```